# SQL Ignoring duplicate values if ID difference larger than

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Lets say I have a simple table:

```
ID value
1   15
2   30
3   **10**
4   **10**
5   16
6   20
7   **15**
8   **15**
9   40
10  70
11  **50**
12  **50**
13  19
14  11
15  3
```

My select should ignore consecutive double values. I know how to do that - I am using lead function
But this eliminates all consecutive duplicates.

```
SELECT   [DetectorParameterValue] 
FROM  (
   SELECT lead(DetectorParameterValue,1) over (partition by runid order by runtime) AS prev_DetectorParameterValue 
   FROM table_Detector 
   WHERE  RunID = @run_id
) AS [InnerDetector] 
WHERE (prev_DetectorParameterValue is null or or prev_DetectorParameterValue <> DetectorParameterValue
```

But it should ignore them only if ID diff is more than 5.

So my select should be

```
ID Value
1   15
2   30
3   10
5   16
6   20
7   15
8   15
9   40
10  70
11  50
13  19
14  11
15  3
```

ID 4 and 12 should be ignored but ID 8 should not because ID 8 - ID 4 is not > 5.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem in disguise.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY ID) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT ID, value
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for prompt answer. I am not sure if this is a correct solution. I get the same result as with Lead function I used. All consecutive duplicate are gone, BUt in my example ID 7 and 8 should both be in a result. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you expect both ID 7 and 8 to be retained.  Maybe you should explain that.

Comment: It's a must. These are values from a sensor (which has a drift where every 40th value is duplicated. But if a duplicate occurs before that it is a legit value so I am not supposed to ignore it. For post-processing, I want to extract only valid data which in this basic sample 7th and 8th IDs are. Hope this is more clear. Thanks for helping.